# Biometrics the only real security

Tags: passwords, biometrics

Since 2FA exploits are increasing, and most end-users are hellbent on using the least secure passwords available, are biometrics the only real security left?

Comment: Attacks against 2FA tokens often also work against biometric tokens... or rather session hijacking that bypasses 2FA does so even if the second factor is biometric.  Biometric IS 2F.

Comment: Many 2FA systems *require* biometrics (like a fingerprint or face scan on your phone to unlock your authenticator). Even these are gamed, as phone fingerprint readers were designed to be a little more error-prone in order to work reliably enough for people to embrace them. This in turn means it's [easy to beat fingerprint scanners](https://www.pcmag.com/news/hacking-fingerprints-is-actually-pretty-easy-and-cheap).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Biometrics alone are not security at all. They're only useful as part of a larger security system.

Comment: Biometrics are more for convenience than security.  The problem there is that you can't change/rotate them.  Once stolen, you are compromised forever.  (or until plastic surgery performed?)

Comment: "Security" against what? You need to be able to define that. There is no silver bullet in security. Biometrics is a very poor replacement for passwords, and are often used for 2FA. If you mean "passwordless" authentication, then when a biometric-based passwordless system is used, there is more going on than just a fingerprint. So, can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Biometrics is the **worst** possible method of *authorization*. You leave your fingertips everywhere, your face can be picked up from hundreds of meters away by using good optics, it applies to your voice as well. A stranger calls you, makes you talk, now you can use AI to generate anything "spoken by you".

Biometrics is OK for *authentication* though but only for that.

> Since 2FA exploits are increasing

Some methods of 2FA like hardware based 2FA are almost impossible to crack except no one has created a method of defending against advanced social engineering attacks and this:

[image: XKCD encryption comics]